# Python Best way to break up large class structure: constants and imports

Tags: python, oop

I have very large file which contains multiple classes and want to break them up with each class getting its own file. I also have a file to interface with those classes:

```
package/
    interface.py
    classALL.py
```

In the end I want something like:

```
package/
    interface.py
    classes/
        classA.py
        classB.py
        classC.py
```

Classes B and C inherit from Class A. What are best practices for doing this? Specifically:

1. Where do I import libraries? Since Class B is a Class A, can I just import everything in Class A?
2. If I need something like *re* in each class, do I need to import it in every class? Will this give me multiple instances of the same library?
3. Where do I put constants? Can I define CONSTANT_A in Class A and be done with it, or do I need to define that in each file?

Comment: Although one massive module with tons of classes can get unwieldy, there is no good reason to go to the other end of the extreme and try to enforce one class per module (i.e. don't try to write java in python).  Better to find a logical and sensible grouping of many classes into a few modules based on their underlying responsibilities within the app

Comment: If you give actual code (and it works), this might better suit [codereview.Se]

Comment: @wim My boss told me to do this :) But I agree that these modules can and should be broken up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give each of your classes a file, and then add them all to a package.

For example you have `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` each with classes `A`, `B` and `C` respectively. You can package all these classes into a single package `abc` by moving the files `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` into a single folder, `abcp` and creating an `__init__.py` file.

The `__init__.py` file may contain something like

```
from .a import A
from .b import B
from .c import C
```

so that it would be possible to directly access the classes from the package.

For example, in `main.py` you can do something like

```
import abcp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    oa = abc.A()
```